# What is the best way to check users locked?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

What is the best way to check which users are locked in Linux/Unix? Does anyone have any experience to share?
I would like to create a script to check it in many servers, so, I will probably need to create something in shell script or Perl, but it will need to run from one server and access all the others I guess.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: `man (1) who`?  I assume you mean logged in, not locked in?

Comment: no, I meant: locked! Today I have a file being created in the /tmp folder from crontab, and I checked the date of this file, if the file have a actual date, user is not locked, but if old, it's locked. I'm just trying to check if someone have any other idea to monitor it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
getent passwd | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -n1 passwd -S
```

Locked accounts are indicated by `LK` in the second column.